# How to accomplish unsupervised separation of subpopulations?

Tags: mixture-distribution, population, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a dataset drawn from a social network that looks Bimodal on logarithmic scales for all attributes (I'll demonstrate only one here):

[image: Bimodal Gaussian Distribution]

I know the variable that would give me a clean separation for the two subpopulations (e.g., gender):

[image][image]

However, I need to come up with the same separation of the two clusters without using **that** binary variable (I could use internal knowledge of the two sub-populations statistics such as averages, stds etc .. ) in an unsupervised manner.

I tried using Gaussian Mixture Models with EM, however, it didn't perform well on this dataset. Clearly what seems normal on logscale it isn't in reality :P

I am looking for a package in python, R or Matlab that would be able to assign individual points to those two clusters.

Comment: It's a good question but it seems pointless. What could be accomplished by such a separation that isn't already achieved by the mixture model estimates?

Comment: The Gaussian mixture model didn't do well on this dataset. I am looking for another way of separation. I also know the ground truth (labels for each population). However, in other similar dataset I don't, therefore, I want to evaluate any approach for separation on this dataset first.

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely how the Gaussian mixture model failed?

Comment: The separation I showed was based on the ground truth (I know the labels). Using Gaussian Mixture model with two components gave a bad results, in terms of assigning each point to one of the two clusters (I got 51% accuracy for balanced number of labeled observations). I think the fact that the bimodal shape distribution appears on a logarithmic scale (Log(x)), when expanded, gaussian mixture can't capture it.

Comment: But of course you fit the Gaussian mixture on the log scale, right? The problem appears to be that even on the log scale neither component is Gaussian.  Regardless, I still wonder about the first question I asked: even if an improved method can be found, what would be accomplished by *any* explicit separation of your population into two subgroups? (The answer to that, if there is one, would help to identify classification methods that work particularly well.)

Comment: In this exact case, the two populations correspond to long-lived spam accounts and short-lived ones. Each sub-population behaves differently, and would be treated differently (One is created with for the intent of spam, the other is compromised accounts). My research includes Characterizing spamming tools and techniques. Examining a number of properties pertaining to spam accounts. Revealing a diverse set of strategies for reaching audiences and sustaining campaigns. While I have small labeled subset, the full data is not, but it follows the same distribution shape.

Comment: But that's exactly my point: the separation would merely (and quite unfairly) label some short-lived accounts as long-lived and conversely. Consider instead using this classification to supply *probability weights* in your follow-on analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the attributes can reliably predict the two populations and you are trying to utilize all attributes to achieve unsupervised separation, then you are describing a typical clustering problem.  It is fairly simple to get started in Python with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

If you have a gold standard of labeled data (vectors of attribute values that characterize each of the two populations), you can also do this in a supervised manner with any of the many classification algorithms (also available in scikit-learn).  Depending on the dimensionality, [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or support vector machine methods like LinearSVC are good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you google semi-supervised learning. It is directly designed to deal with situations where there is a small labelled set and a much larger unlabelled set, and you try to learn from both. In this situation, I feel that training your model with all the data but no labels (unsupervised) or with labels but not all the data (supervised) is very wasteful. Why not use everything you have?

I'm not very knowledgeable about the details of semi-supervised algorithms so I think you are probably better off spending a bit of time reading about it from review articles you can find online than listening to me. This paper is a little old by ML standards (2007) but it's very heavily cited and seems solid: http://aims.cse.msu.edu/~cse802/notes/SSLsurvey.pdf